# best practise: Refactoring a docker compose file that no service has a build property

Tags: azure, docker-compose

I want to deploy a complex webapp with [azure docker compose web service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container). Unfortunately this [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux#docker-compose-options) doesn't support "build" property. So how can i replace it?

Comment: You have to build the images beforehand and push them into a docker registry that is accessible by that service

Answer (score 0):

To support multiple build configurations and deployments, split the compose.yml into several files.

Then, when you need to build and push, specify the files explicitly:

```bash
docker compose --file compose.yml --file compose.build.yml build
docker compose --file compose.yml --file compose.build.yml push
docker --context azure compose --file compose.yml --file compose.azure.yml up
```

etc.

As a convenience, if you don't provide any file directives, docker compose will automatically load `compose.yml` and `compose.override.yml` (or, the legacy `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml`). So its convenient to setup a local debug environment  in the `.override` file as that can be accessed implicitly.

Comment: How does this solve the issue of App Service not supporting Build in Compose files?

Comment: you, er, don't deploy the `.override.yml` or `.build.yml` with the `build:` clause.

Comment: Oh, I see (coffee still kicks in).